# my query is showing heidisql error a dont know how to fix

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

SQL Error (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.room id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT hotel_id,room_id,room_number,MAX(a.tc) AS "Count",MAX(tp) AS   "MostProfit" FROM
(SELECT hotel_id,rooms.room_id,room_number,COUNT(rooms.room_id) AS  "tc",SUM(room_price) AS "tp" FROM rooms JOIN bookings 
ON rooms.room_id = bookings.room_id
GROUP BY rooms.room_id) a GROUP BY hotel_id
```

[trying to get the rooms of hotels that got the most profit in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154224/trying-to-get-the-rooms-of-hotels-that-got-the-most-profit-in-a-query)

Comment: You really need to explain what you want to do.  It might surprise you, but a non-functioning query does not necessary express what you want to do.

Comment: its query Get room which made the most profits for each hotel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc the answer is useless and does not work

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that you need to convert your group by clause to

```
GROUP BY hotel_id, room_id, room_number
```

since the other columns `tc` and `tp` are aggregated, and no need to be included in the group by list, whereas `room_id` and `room_number` are not.